# Can't navigation between xaml in frame?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I have got issues . Why did not it navigate to other xaml? Where is wrong?
So, I was trying to make it that can navigated between two or more xaml in a frame.

Here is link : https://github.com/Englbach/MutiViewInRootPage

```xaml
 <SplitView.Content>
    <!-- OnNavigatingToPage we synchronize the selected item in the nav menu with the current page.
         OnNavigatedToPage we move keyboard focus to the first item on the page after it's loaded. -->
    <Frame x:Name="AppShellFrame">
       <Frame.ContentTransitions>
           <TransitionCollection>
               <NavigationThemeTransition>
                   <NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
                      <EntranceNavigationTransitionInfo />
                   </NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
               </NavigationThemeTransition>
           </TransitionCollection>
       </Frame.ContentTransitions>
   </Frame>
</SplitView.Content>
```

```c#
public static AppShell Current = null;

public List<NavMenuItem> NavList { get; } = new List<NavMenuItem>(new[]
{
     new NavMenuItem()
     {
          Symbol = Symbol.Add,
          Label = "Add feed",
          DestPage = typeof(RootPages),
          Arguments = typeof(AddFeedView)
     },
     new NavMenuItem()
     {
          Symbol = Symbol.Edit,
          Label = "Edit feeds",
          DestPage = typeof(RootPages),
          Arguments = typeof(EditFeedView)
     }
});
public AppShell()
{
     this.InitializeComponent();
     Current = this;
}

private void NavMenuList_ItemInvoked(object sender, ListViewItem e)
{
     NavMenuList.SelectedIndex = -1;
     var item = (NavMenuItem)((NavMenuListView)sender).ItemFromContainer(e);
     if(item!=null)
     {
          AppFrame.Navigate(typeof(RootPages), item.Arguments);
     }
}
```

Comment: What does your debugger tell you? i.e. Are you hitting the event handler? is the item being retrieved correctly?

Comment: No error. When I click on each item on navmenuitem but there is no anything.

Comment: I want to click each item on navmenuitem that it must be navigated to other xaml in that frame

Comment: Ex: Default RootPages in Frame.I click on add feed and then navigate to AddFeedView be replaced by RootPages.

Comment: Does it hit a breakpoint set in your method?

Comment: It run normal but does not navigation. There are no breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

You probably followed the official [Navigation menu (XAML) sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39370783/cant-navigation-between-xaml-in-frame) to design your layout.

There are two tiny problems in your demo.

1. Each time the items in the `NavMenuList` is clicked, the `NavMenuList_ItemInvoked` event in the AppShell.xaml.cs should be triggered. And in this event, you navigated again and again to your `RootPages`, and together pass the navigation parameter(item.Arguments) to the `RootPages` like this `AppFrame.Navigate(typeof(RootPages), item.Arguments);`, and the argument is actually your destination.

You can modify the code here like this:

```
private void NavMenuList_ItemInvoked(object sender, ListViewItem e)
{
    //NavMenuList.SelectedIndex = -1;
    var item = (NavMenuItem)((NavMenuListView)sender).ItemFromContainer(e);
    if (item != null)
    {
        //AppFrame.Navigate(typeof(RootPages), item.Arguments);
        if (item.DestPage != null &&
            item.DestPage != this.AppFrame.CurrentSourcePageType)
        {
            this.AppFrame.Navigate(item.DestPage, item.Arguments);
        }
    }
}
```

2. Then here comes the second problem, as I said, the `Arguments` should be navigation parameter, for example, I navigate to `AddFeedView` page and I want to send a message "balalala", then we can code like this: `AppFrame.Navigate(typeof(AddFeedView), "balalala");`. This means, you confused with your `DestPage` and `Arguments`.

You can modify your `NavList` like this:

```
public List<NavMenuItem> NavList { get; } = new List<NavMenuItem>(new[]
{
    new NavMenuItem()
    {
        Symbol = Symbol.Add,
        Label = "Add feed",
        DestPage = typeof(AddFeedView),
        Arguments = typeof(RootPages)
    },
    new NavMenuItem()
    {
        Symbol = Symbol.Edit,
        Label = "Edit feeds",
        DestPage = typeof(EditFeedView),
        Arguments = typeof(RootPages)
    }
});
```

In additional, if you want your `AppFrame` to navigate to the `RootPages` at first by default, you can code like this:

```
public AppShell()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Current = this;
    AppFrame.Navigate(typeof(RootPages));
}
```